# Mapbox map already initialized

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mapbox

I have an Angular service function to build a mapbox map like so:

```
app.service("MapService", [function(){

    //mapbox vars
    var map = {
      minZoom: 11,
      id: "xxxxxxxx",
      token: "xxxxxxxx"
    };


    //build map
    this.buildMap = function(lat, lon, zoom){

      //map bounds
      var southWest = L.latLng(54.04407014753034, -0.745697021484375),
          northEast = L.latLng(53.45698455620496, -2.355194091796875),
          bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

      //build map object
      L.mapbox.accessToken = map.token;
      map.obj = L.mapbox.map("map", map.id, {
        maxBounds: bounds,
        zoomControl: false,
        minZoom: map.minZoom,
        attributionControl: false
      }).setView([lat, lon], zoom, {
        pan: { animate: true },
        zoom: { animate: true } 
      });

    }

  }]);
```

This simply populates a div:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

When I go to a new Angular view and call this function again (to populate a new `div` with id `map` with the map) it gives me the error:

`Map container is already initialized`

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to destroy the map before reinitializing it. Use the following

```
if(map.obj != undefined) map.obj.remove();
```

before

```
map.obj = L.mapbox.map("map", map.id, {
```

Comment: This gets rid of the error but doesn't rebuild the map. I just get an empty map container on the second load. I've discovered that adding a 100ms timeout on building the map after the route has loaded works. Must be to do with the controller executing the service function before the DOM has updated with the new view.

Answer (score 0):

Using a directive is much more suitable for this kind of purpose, you won't run into stuff like this. In the following directive i'm using Leaflet, but it's just the same as using Mapbox (Mapbox is an extended version of Leaflet):

```
angular.module('app').directive('leaflet', [
  function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div></div>',
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
          scope.$emit('leaflet-ready', new L.Map(element[0]));
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Use it in your view:

```
<leaflet></leaflet>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('map1Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('leaflet-ready', function (e, leaflet) {
    // leaflet var contains map instance, do stuff
  })
});
```

Here's an example of the concept: http://plnkr.co/edit/SFgGhVUtBOqsIwYuwNuv?p=preview

Comment: If I have it in a directive, doesn't that make it harder for other interactions on the page to trigger things like adding layers to the map? I initially put the code in a service because the map could easily be accessed and changed there without having to watch scope variables.